# Make git ignore and keep local changes to some files (vs different version in remote)

Tags: git

I have a local working copy of a git repo, and it needs to have some changes in order to work for local testing, but I don't want those changes to be sent to remote when I do `add --all` and `commit`.

Basically the files are:

```
/protected/config/*
/protected/components/UserIdentity.php
```

I tried adding those into `.git/info/exclude`, but `git status` still shows the changes (which are already made to the files).

I need the files to stay in the remote, but locally they must be changed and immune to eg. `pull`.

Is there a way?

Comment: Third answer in the linked question might be of most interest to you.

Comment: I don't see a point in marking this as duplicate since the linked question is quite a bit different and I already received the relevant answer here too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of this [site](http://one-line-it.blogspot.fr/2013/08/git-ignore-changes-in-tracked-files.html) proposes a solution:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

Will ignore local modifications on tracked files and

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

will undo the previous command. This work even with `git commit --all` as assumed-unchanged files are not staged.

Reading [git-update-index man-page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) you can also see that this bit is not reset after you committed, so you either have to `--no-assume-unchanged` the file/path or do a `git update-index --really-refresh` to get every modification back.

If merging with something (branch/tag/commit) (for example when doing a `git pull`) which has modifications in that file, you will get a

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
```

error and the merge is aborted.

So, no, it won't work with git-pull, if there are modifications upstream.

Comment: Looks good; will the file then remain changed after pull, too?

Comment: okay, should work oh for me, tnx